# Append to playlist from command line

Tags: mplayer

Suppose I have an instance of smplayer running playing a playlist. Is there a way to add videos from command line to that playlist? Any other media player where I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

`smplayer -add-to-playlist file`

From the man-page:

```
-add-to-playlist
If there is another instance running, the media will be added to   that instance's playlist. If there is no  other  instance,
this option will be ignored and the files will be opened in a new instance.
```